# Cannot access my SSD storage / Wrong Memory Setup on Fedora

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, fedora

I cannot write further to my file system, as my OS is telling me that the ssd is full.

When I was first setting my Linux Fedora (35), I only gave it access to 50 GB of my disk, as I was thinking that this is going to be the storage only for the OS.

I have 1 TB of storage overall, majority of which is unused.

I really do not know how to "tell" to my OS now that I have plenty of storage left.

This is the result of `sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: --- (I hided it)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  524MB   523MB   primary   fat32        lba
 2      524MB   967GB   967GB   primary   ntfs
 3      967GB   968GB   629MB   primary   fat32        boot
 4      968GB   1000GB  32,4GB  extended
 5      968GB   969GB   1074MB  logical   ext4
 6      969GB   1000GB  31,3GB  logical   btrfs


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram0: 8590MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0,00B  8590MB  8590MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

And this is `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G  174M   16G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           6,3G  2,1M  6,3G   1% /run
/dev/----0n1p6   30G   26G  4,0G  87% /
tmpfs            16G  348M   16G   3% /tmp
/dev/----0n1p6   30G   26G  4,0G  87% /home
/dev/----0n1p5  976M  237M  673M  27% /boot
/dev/----0n1p3  599M   14M  585M   3% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3,2G  184K  3,2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Where are my 1000GBs?

Comment: It looks like you have dual boot setup with Windows that takes about first 968 GiB.

Comment: Can I remove it only from terminal? How should I remove the other partition. I got a new PC, so having other OS would be extremely unlikely

Comment: IMO the best and safest option is to reinstall with reclaiming the whole space that Windows (Partition number 2) uses. I would remove all partitions in Anaconda (fedora installer) and then use automatic partitioning to keep it simple. You can read more in official docs - https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/install-guide/install/Installing_Using_Anaconda/#sect-installation-gui-storage-partitioning

Comment: I will try this. Thanks!